# How to make edges stretch on UV Map

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

[image]

Hello, just a small question: where is the toggle to make the image stretch out the end pixels to avoid repetition? I'd forgotten where it was.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the repeat parameter to extend in the image texture node. As you can see in my exemple the UV unwrapped outside of the picture contained stretched pixel.

[image]